# JSLint keeps telling me that my functions are out of scope. It isn't making any sense

Tags: javascript

1=rock
2=paper
3=scissor
When I am using JSLint to check my code for errors, it is throwing a whole bunch of messages at me saying that some of my functions are out of scope. I have already spent 2 hours fiddling with the code trying to get it to work, but to no avail. Maybe someone can take a look at it with fresh eyes. Thanks.
    var computerchoice = 0;
    var humanchoice = 0;
    var computerscore = 0;
    var humanscore = 0;
    var roundnumber = 0;
    var tiescore = 0;
    var winner;
    var loser;

```
function SwitchToGameScreen() {
    document.getElementById("startscreen").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("gamescreen").style.display = "block";
}
function resetgame() {
    document.getElementById("humanrock").style.border = "none";
    document.getElementById("humanpaper").style.border = "none";
    document.getElementById("humanscissor").style.border = "none";
    document.getElementById("computerrock").style.border = "none";
    document.getElementById("computerpaper").style.border = "none";
    document.getElementById("computerscissor").style.border = "none";
}

function human_chooses_rock() {
    humanchoice = 1;
    document.getElementById("rock").style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
    document.getElementById("humanchoice").innerHTML = "Rock";
    EvaluateRound;
}

function human_chooses_paper() {
    humanchoice = 2;
    document.getElementById("paper").style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
    document.getElementById("humanchoice").innerHTML = "Paper";
    EvaluateRound;
}


function human_chooses_scissor() {
    humanchoice = 3;
    document.getElementById("scissor").style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
    document.getElementById("humanchoice").innerHTML = "Scissor";
    EvaluateRound;
}

function EvaluateRound() {
    roundnumber = roundnumber + 1;
    computerchoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if (humanchoice === 1 && computerchoice === 1) {
        tiescore = tiescore + 1;
        winner = "nobody";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (humanchoice === 1 && computerchoice === 2) {
        computerscore = computerscore + 1;
        winner = "Computer";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (humanchoice === 1 && computerchoice === 2) {
        humanscore = humanscore + 1;
        winner = "Human";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (humanchoice === 2 && computerchoice === 1) {
        humanscore = humanscore + 1;
        winner = "Human";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (humanchoice === 2 && computerchoice === 2) {
        tiescore = tiescore + 1;
        winner = "nobody";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (humanchoice === 2 && computerchoice === 3) {
        computerscore = computerscore + 1;
        winner = "Computer";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (humanchoice === 3 && computerchoice === 1) {
        computerscore = computerscore + 1;
        winner = "Computer";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (humanchoice === 3 && computerchoice === 2) {
        humanscore = humanscore + 1;
        winner = "Human";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (humanchoice === 3 && computerchoice === 3) {
        tiescore = tiescore + 1;
        winner = "nobody";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (roundnumber === 10) {
        document.getElementById("gamescreen").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("finishscreen").style.display = "block";
        UpdateStats();
    }
    if (computerchoice === 1) {
        document.getElementById("computerrock").style.border = "thick solid     #0000FF";
    }
    if (computerchoice === 2) {
        document.getElementById("computerpaper").style.border = "thick solid     #0000FF";
    }
    if (computerchoice === 3) {
        document.getElementById("computerscissor").style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
    }
}
function UpdateStats() {
    document.getElementById("humanscore").innerHTML = humanscore;
    document.getElementById("computerscore").innerHTML = computerscore;
    document.getElementById("tiescore").innerHTML = tiescore;
    document.getElementById("roundnumber").innerHTML = roundnumber;
    document.getElementById("computerchoice").innerHTML = computerchoice;
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = winner;
}  document.getElementById("hidestartscreenshowgamescreen").addEventListener("click", SwitchToGameScreen);

document.getElementById("rock").addEventListener("click",human_chooses_rock);

document.getElementById("paper").addEventListener("click",human_chooses_paper);

document.getElementById("scissor").addEventListener("click",human_chooses_scissor);

document.getElementById("rock").addEventListener("click", resetgame);

document.getElementById("paper").addEventListener("click", resetgame);

document.getElementById("scissor").addEventListener("click", resetgame);
```

Comment: It does make sense. JSLint expects you to declare any variable or function before using it. Also, the functions don't return a function in your code, hence the event listeners won't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the functions are in the correct order. So that a function is declared before I call the function in another function.

Comment: ??? You're calling `SwitchToGameScreen` and all the other functions when attaching event handlers, a way before you're declaring the functions. They are hoisted, yes, but I said, "_JSLint expects_" you to declare them before they are used.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are talking about how the event listeners won't work.

Comment: It should be `.addEventListener("click", SwitchToGameScreen);` without the `()` after the function name (and similar for the other listeners). Also, several of your functions have the reverse problem with `EvaluateRound` when it should be `EvaluateRound()`. Note also that JSLint doesn't just check for *errors*, it also checks for *style*, so it may reject code that works.

Comment: Please get familiar with [Crockford's code conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) to understand JSLint better.